# How to initialize a TFilter with a known Video Capture source without using TSysDevEnum.GetMoniker?

Tags: delphi, directshow, dspack

Is it possible to create/initailize a TFilter object with a known Video Capture source without using TSysDevEnum.GetMoniker(...)?

The Video Capture Source's name and other details are already known and can be obtained by GraphEdit Filter Browser. The intention is to speed up the initialization of TFilter and attach it to the FilterGraph programmatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, [you need to do it via moniker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd377566%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). It depends on actual COM class backing the video source filter, however almost always there is no unique `CLSID` and it is impossible to instantiate it not via moniker.

If you have moniker display name, you can use `MkParseDisplayName` to quickly obtain IMoniker bypassing enumeration. Or you can enumerate and compare moniker's display name to the one you already hold.

> To select an audio or video capture device, use the System Device
>   Enumerator, described in the topic Using the System Device Enumerator.
>   The System Device Enumerator returns a collection of device monikers,
>   selected by device category. A moniker is a COM object that contains
>   information about another object. Monikers enable the application to
>   get information about an object without actually creating the object.

Comment: Thanks. In a test program, if I enumerate all available filters from CLSID_VideoInputDeviceCategory, it takes about 10 seconds to fill the list. After that when I select the one I want, SysDev.GetMoniker(ItemNumber) takes another 10 seconds to return. Alternatively, if I build the graph in graph editor and save the GRF file and then load that file directly into a vanilla GraphEditor the result is almost instantaneous! How do you use MkParseDisplayName?

Comment: It is hard to say why it takes 10 seconds, but there is something wrong about it. It is never this way unless something is broken. I have a simple utility that enumerates stuff here [EnumerateVideoCaptureFilterCapabilities](http://trac.assembla.com/roatl-utilities/browser/trunk/EnumerateVideoCaptureFilterCapabilities/Win32/Release) and you can check if it also takes 10 second. If no, maybe the problem is in your enumerating code?

Comment: [`MkParseDisplayName`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms691253%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is straightforward - you pass the string (e.g. "@device:pnp:\\?\pci#ven_109e&dev_036e&subsys_18511851&rev_02#4&39c3dd91&0&08f0#{65e8773d-8f56-11d0-a3b9-00a0c9223196}\global") in `szUserName` parameter and you get your moniker back.

Comment: I really want to compare the performance difference using "EnumerateVideoCaptureFilterCapabilities", but unfortunately I cannot any external executables on this machine.

Comment: You are very correct! It should not have taken that long. I had drivers for another Capture card still installed on the system. When I uninstalled the unused drivers the response became instantaneous! Thanks!